# What does '&' mean in C++ when it comes before a method declaration

Tags: c++11, methods, ampersand

For example, if a method is defined as the following:

```
  ILDCRTParams &GetParams() const;
```

Is this any different then:

```
 ILDCRTParams& GetParams() const;
```

I'm using C++ 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are exactly the same. The return type is `ILDCRTParams&`

Answer (score 1):

No, they mean exactly the same thing. C++ is a token-based language, where whitespace is insignificant between tokens except to act as a separator. You can write it as

```
ILDCRTParams &GetParams() const;
ILDCRTParams& GetParams() const;
ILDCRTParams&GetParams() const;
ILDCRTParams & GetParams() const;
```

or even

```
ILDCRTParams             &GetParams(         )const;
```

without any change in meaning.

Semantically, the `&` effectively modifies `ILDCRTParams`, but syntactically, it modifies `GetParams()`: `&GetParams()` specifies that `GetParams()` returns a reference. For that reason, some people prefer to place it immediately next to `ILDCRTParams`, but others next to `GetParams()`.

Comment: Indeed you even can write `ILDCRTParams /* whatever that may be */ & /* Let's see if anyone still understands this code */ GetParams /* yeah, right. */ ( /* Nothing to see here, move along */) /* yeah, one more comment; comments make the code readable, don't they? */ const;` :-)